# How did Obama "Fundamentally transform America?"

Tags: united-states, barack-obama, conservatism

Most conservatives I talk to or hear about are very hot and bothered by what Obama has "done to America".  They are very passionate about it.  So passionate that I would like to understand where they are coming from.

But, I have yet to get an objective source of information for their claims.  This [post](https://www.toddstarnes.com/column/bush-took-a-knee-when-obama-fundamentally-transformed-america) from Todd Starnes is typically the kind of thing I come across.  (Don't click if you don't want to support him - he has plenty of advertisements).

One example (from Todd's post):

> When Obama apologized for America on foreign soil Bush was silent.

My questions would be:

1. Which incident(s) are referred to, and
2. What were the measurable consequences of that?

What are some best effort (at being objective) sources of information that can help me understand the conservative argument of how Obama fundamentally changed America?

I consider myself centrist, so when a conservative says something like "Obama declared war on police officers" I do not understand what they are referring to.  The information I'm looking for would help me understand why conservatives think things like that, even if it's a cultural thing and not necessarily policy.

Books, articles, blogs, whatever. I'd prefer sources that aren't promoting a news organization such as Fox News or some other for-profit entity.  But, if that's the best there is, that's fine.

By objective, I mean claims that include references that point to evidence.  I know there isn't anything perfect out there. Again, best effort is fine.

UPDATE: I've updated to reflect that I'm looking for best effort, here.

Comment: Are you just interested in that one claim or do you want a general analysis of his legacy?

Comment: That claim is one example.  I'm looking for a detailed analysis that goes into the most popular claims.  Popular is subjective, so I provided that one article as an example of the frequent popular claims I run into.  A book would do, too, if it was from a an author who has demonstrated objectivity in other works.  I'd label authors like Ben Shapiro, Dinesh D'souza, etc... as extremely biased.  I would would not call them objective.

Comment: @lp - what's your example of an objective author?

Comment: @user4012 Al Franken.  Just kidding.  I don't know... Somewhere along the lines of text book.  Like Michael Genovese.  But I'm open to illumination.

Comment: There's not going to be an 'objective' source for their claims as their claims are specifically *not* objective.

Comment: This question could be interpreted in two ways. One way is to interpret it as "please help me read the minds of millions of conservative Obama critics", which is impossible because "conservatives" are not a homogeneous hive-mind. The other way to interpret this question is as "please summarize all the effects of 8 years of Obama presidency on the United States". One could write a whole book about this. This question is too broad to answer adequately.

Comment: Goodness, people. I'm not looking for gospel.  Just best effort. Even if it's right leaning but provides decent references, that's fine.  I didn't ask anyone to summarize 8 years of Obama in their response, either.  Yes, someone could write a book about it.  Maybe that book is what I'm looking for.

Comment: It is unfortunate that this was on hold because he certainly fundamentally changed America. I can say that even if I don't support him politically. He was the first to use social media as intended. He was the first to be from outside the establishment (Remember, at the beginning even blacks said he was not black enough) even though he became part of it at the end. He usurp some of the power from congress and whether you think that is right or wrong, it changed how the public sees the presidency and what it can do for the average American.

Comment: @FrankCedeno if by usurping you mean executive orders, he actually did very little of that.

Comment: @blip little is subjective, who is to judge how much is just enough and what is too much. That fact is that there are some very illegal ones by rule of law, but like most things in politics, it's not logic but feelings. Example: The recent flap about Trump defunding subsidies to Health Insurance Companies. You can't use Exec Orders to fund anything, but Congress sat back and let it happen. Then there is DACA. My point is now people expect the President to wave his wand and make laws, fund things and wave laws aside

Comment: @FrankCedeno the counterpoint to that is that the president didn't fundamentally change anything, but rather had to react to the fact that congress fundamentally changed things by becoming unable to pass legislation via compromise.

Comment: @blip, not much of a counter point if congress is doing what it does, and if congress doesn't want to do anything, it doesn't mean the president should do something.  There is an important reason why gridlock was built into the system, If people refuse to learn from history it will repeat.

Comment: @FrankCedeno we can go in circles here...as it doesn't mean the president *shouldn't* do something, either. Gridlock wasn't built into the system. Compromise was. If congress fails at that, then...

Comment: @blip, yes I know you disagree. What you are describing is called Tyranny.  This is something built into the constitution because those who wrote it feared this very thing. No matter how well intended the person holding the office of the president, it is not up to him to enact laws or fund anything. The purpose of the separation of powers is exactly gridlock. It is the difference between mob rule and sober calculated approach to governing.

Comment: @FrankCedeno you're right. That's why the president *can't* enact laws or fund anything. They can merely dictate how said laws are implemented via executive orders, of which congress has every right to over-rule. The system is actually working as intended.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's a reference to [this speech](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KrefKCaV8m4) in which Obama said that he wants to fundamentally transform America (he then names some examples, such as mainstreet over wallstreet, improving things for the middle class, affordable college, etc).

He went into this again in an [interview with Bill O'Reilly](http://www.politifact.com/truth-o-meter/article/2014/feb/06/what-barack-obama-has-said-about-fundamentally-tra/), where he again mentions good wages, public schools, etc.

When the Right wing talks about Obama "fundamentally transforming America" They are usually referring to a change in culture(in a way they do not like).

Examples:

- http://www.glennbeck.com/content/blog/glenn/five-days-away-from-fundamentally-transforming-the-united-states-of-america-again/
- (https://www.cnsnews.com/commentary/dr-paul-kengor/how-obama-made-good-his-promise-fundamentally-transform-united-states)